# How to filter by image column in Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column which may have an image otherwise it is null.

How can I add a filter such that only rows with images will show up?

My column is defined as

```
case 'image':
column.type = "string";
column.template = ' #if(' + key + ') { # <a class="thumbnail" ><img src="#=' + key + '#" ng-click="vm.imageClicked(\'#=' + key + '#\' )" >   </a> #}#';
column.filterable = {
    cell: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
break;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Kendo version 2014.2.716, there is no way to filter by null so the best option I have come up with is to have a calculated Boolean filed.

Here is the code for it.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Xavier/ihUj